# Can't read Javascript cookie in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core

I'm trying to read a cookie created by the client in Javascript like:

```
seasons={"2210":2,"2901":3,"6887":1};expires=Mon, 11 Mar 2019 16:49:15 GMT;path=/
```

I can see the cookie correctly in the browser, but when I try to read it in the controller, all I see is:

[image]

I'm guessing that "MyAntiforgeryCookie" is the cookie I'm looking for. Do I need to decrypt it?

I tried looking for "Antiforgery asp net core", but seems most answers are old, or are about AJAX requests. This is on ANY request to the controller.

Comment: That’s not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Antyforgery cookie is part of anti-CRSF and is added automatically to forms and will be checked if you'll put [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on action.

Comment: @Ryan Ops, bit fast when copypasting... it's a hack of small string bits...  That's the result withing quotes so to speak. But the construction of the cookie is not the issue, I believe

Comment: @WueF I dont have the attribute anywhere. And this happens even if I type the URL into the browser, so no form POST.

Comment: It’s the cookie part of CSRF protection; it will be on every request. Your cookie isn’t there. Where do you see the cookie in the browser? Is it also in the request headers?

Comment: My cookie is not in the request headers. I can see it in Chrome's application tab. https://pasteboard.co/HbqSwd5.png

Comment: After playing around a bit (not sure what did it), it is in the header `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]` `seasons={"2210":2,"2901":1,"6887":1}; MyAntiforgeryCookie=CfD.......` But how do I get it into Request.Cookies?